# Importing multiple invoices (.PDF) in R. Turning them from strings to a tibble

Tags: r, pdf, stringr, readr

So I'm doing a project where I need to load a numerous amount of .pdfs into R. This part is somewhat covered. The problem is when importing the pdfs into R, every line is a string. Not all the information in de the string is relevant. And in some of the cases information is missing. So I want to select the info I need and place them into a tibble for further analysis.

Importing the pdf's are done by pdftools. It's working, hints or tips are welcome though

```
invoice_pdfs = list.files(pattern="*.pdf")                   # gather all the .pdf in current wd. 

invoice_list <- map(invoice_pdfs, .f = function(invoices){   # Using the purrr::map function .
                            pdf_text(invoices) %>%           # extracting text from listed pdf file(s)            
                            readr::read_lines() %>%          # read all text from pdf
                            str_squish() %>%                 # clear all white space in text.
                            str_to_lower                     # convert string to lower case
                         })
```

reproducible example:

```
invoice_example <- c("invoice",                                                                         
"to: rade ris",                                                                    
"cane nompany",                                                                   
"kakber street 23d",                                                               
"nork wey",                                                                        
"+223 (0)56 015 6542",                                                             
"invoice id: 85600023",                                                            
"date reference product product reference weigth amount",                           
"01-02-2016 840000023 product a 24.45.6 de6583621 14.900 kg a 50 per tonne 745,00",
"07-02-2016 840000048 product b 24.45.7 qf8463641 19.000 kg a 50 per tonne 950,00", 
"03-02-2016 840000032 product b 24.34.2 qf8463641 4.000 kg per tonne 250,00",      
"02-02-2016 840000027 ke7801465 1.780 kg per tonne 89,00",                         
"subtotal 2.034,00",                                                               
"sales tax 183,06",                                                                
"total 2.217,06")
```

So here is where the problem starts.
What I've tried is using stringr and rebus to select specific parts of the text. I've made the following function to search the document for specific string, it returns the rownumber:

```
word_finder <- function(x, findWord){
                word_hit <- x %>%                           # temp for storing TRUE or FALSE
                  str_detect(pattern = fixed(findWord)) 
                 which(word_hit == TRUE)                    # give rownumber if TRUE
                }
```

And the following searchpatterns:

```
detect_date <- dgt(2) %R% "-" %R% dgt(2) %R% "-" %R% dgt(2)
detect_money <-  optional(DIGIT) %R% optional(".") %R% one_or_more(DIGIT) %R% "," %R% dgt(2) 
detect_invoice_num <- str_trim(SPC %R% dgt(8) %R% optional(SPC))
```

The next step should be to make a tibble (or data frame) with the column names `c("date", "reference", "product", "product reference", "weight", "amount")` I've also tried making a tibble of the whole `invoice_example` problem is the missing info in some fields and the column names don’t match the corresponding value's.

So I would like to make some function that uses the search pattern and places that specific value to a predestined column. I've got no clue how to get this done. Or maybe I should handle this completely different?

final result should be something like this.

reproducible example:

```
invoice_nr <- c("85600023", "85600023", "85600023", "85600023" )
date <- c( "01-02-2016", "07-02-2016", "03-02-2016", "02-02-2016")
reference <- c( "840000023", "840000048", "840000032", "840000027")
product_id <- c( "de6583621", "qf8463641", "qf8463641", "ke7801465")
weight <- c("14.900", "19.000", "4.000", "1.780")
amount <- c("745.00", "950.00", "250.00", "89.00")

example_tibble <- tibble(invoice_nr, date, reference, product_id, weight, amount)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  invoice_nr date       reference product_id weight amount
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>  <chr> 
1 85600023   01-02-2016 840000023 de6583621  14.900 745.00
2 85600023   07-02-2016 840000048 qf8463641  19.000 950.00
3 85600023   03-02-2016 840000032 qf8463641  4.000  250.00
4 85600023   02-02-2016 840000027 ke7801465  1.780  89.00
```

Any suggested ways of dealing with this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use the functions of `library(stringr)` to achieve your goal (I skipped the `rebus` part as this seems to eb anyways 'just'  a helper for creatign teh regex, which I did by hand):

```
library(tidyverse)
parse_invoice <- function(in_text) {
  ## define regex, some assumptions:
  ## product id is 2 lower characters followed by 7 digits
  ## weight is some digits with a dot followed by kg
  ## amount is some digits at the end with a comma
  all_regex <- list(date       = "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}",
                    reference  = "\\d{9}",
                    product_id = "[a-z]{2}\\d{7}",
                    weight     = "\\d+\\.\\d+ kg",
                    amount     = "\\d+,\\d+$")
  ## look only at lines where there is invoice data
  rel_lines <- str_subset(in_text, all_regex$date)
  ## extract the pieces from the regex
  ret <- as_tibble(map(all_regex, str_extract, string = rel_lines))
  ## clean up the data
  ret %>%
    mutate(invoice_nr = str_extract(str_subset(in_text, "invoice id:"), "\\d{8}"),
           date       = as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y"),
           weight     = as.numeric(str_replace(weight, "(\\d+.\\d+) kg", "\\1")),
           amount     = as.numeric(str_replace(amount, ",", "."))
    ) %>%
    select(invoice_nr,
           date,
           reference,
           product_id,
           weight,
           amount)

}
```

> ```
> str(parse_invoice(invoice_example))
> # Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       4 obs. of  6 variables:
> #  $ invoice_nr: chr  "85600023" "85600023" "85600023" "85600023"
> #  $ date      : Date, format: "2016-02-01" "2016-02-07" ...
> #  $ reference : chr  "840000023" "840000048" "840000032" "840000027"
> #  $ product_id: chr  "de6583621" "qf8463641" "qf8463641" "ke7801465"
> #  $ weight    : num  14.9 19 4 1.78
> #  $ amount    : num  745 950 250 89
> ```

Comment: ```rebus``` is indeed a helper; it’s a more human readable code if I may say. It's easier to apply for someone like me, who hasn't got any experience in regex. The code by [@thothal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125751/thothal) shows me its valuable to learn and regex seems to give more control in selecting the correct parts of a string. Thanks for showing me and providing this answer, its exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not familiar with `rebus` I've rewritten your code. Assuming the invoices are at least somewhat structured the same I could generate a `tibble` from your example. You would just have to apply this to your whole list and then `purrr::reduce` it to a big `tibble`:

```
df <- tibble(date=na.omit(str_extract(invoice_example,"\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")))
df %>% mutate(invoice_nr=na.omit(sub("invoice id: ","",str_extract(invoice_example,"invoice id: [0-9]+"))),
              reference=na.omit(sub("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} ","",str_extract(invoice_example,"\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{9}"))),
              product_id=na.omit(str_extract(invoice_example,"[:lower:]{2}\\d{7}")),
              weight=na.omit(sub(" kg","",str_extract(invoice_example,"[0-9\\.]+ kg"))),
              amount=na.omit(sub("tonne ","",str_extract(invoice_example,"tonne [0-9,]+"))))
```